# How can I get a valid QGLContext in Windows 16 bit color?

Tags: c++, windows, qt, opengl

I have an existing/working Qt 5 QGLWidget that uses OpenGL Desktop and GLSL shader version 1.5 on Windows 7. When my monitor/display driver is set to 32 bit True Color works, but when I change to 16 bit mode it does not work.

```
QGLFormat::openGLVersionFlags()
```

Using this returns only OpenGL version 1.1 is supported whereas in 32 bit True Color it reports 4.2. My video card is nVidia GTX 670.

I believe this has to do with requesting the correct QGLContext to be created, but I'm not sure what options I need to be requesting and testing it has proven to be shots in the dark. Here is what I've currently tried from searching online:

```
QGLFormat f = QGLFormat::defaultFormat();
f.setVersion(4, 2); // also tried "3, 2" which coincides with GLSL 1.5
f.setProfile(QGLFormat::CoreProfile);
f.setDepth(true);
QGLFormat::setDefaultFormat(f);
```

I have had success with the underlying window by creating the context myself with winapi, but I cannot find what's wrong with the Qt version of the code.

I would at least like to figure out the situation and not crash because a context that supports my required OpenGL version was not created.

Comment: Who uses that, there hasn't been a 16 bit color pipeline since the days of voodoo.

Comment: My only reply is it can be done and was, now I'm trying to prevent it

Comment: It looks like the best I can do is detect the mode and exit. Even though my Win32 window code works, I can't seem to get a similar QGLWidget to work.